# Andromda Project Creation Using Maven

Tags: maven, andromda

I have created an Andromda Project using following command

mvn org.andromda.maven.plugins:andromdapp-maven-plugin:3.4-SNAPSHOT:generate

this command creates project for latest andromda version and spring version 3.x
but problem is we can not integrate acegi security into it that requires spring version <2.5

So i want to know what command i can use to generate a project that will have a previous version of andromda and spring and will be able to integrate acegi security to that project.

Or are there any steps that can be followed to downgrade current Project's Andromda and Spring versions???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up for the available versions of andromda on the internet and when generating the project in the command
`mvn org.andromda.maven.plugins:andromdapp-maven-plugin:3.4-SNAPSHOT:generate` replace 3.4-SNAPSHOT with the version you want to use. For example I want to use newer 3.4 then I will write the command as `mvn org.andromda.maven.plugins:andromdapp-maven-plugin:3.4:generate`

I was unable to do this as I was unable to look for proper version of andromda